# How do I upload an image and go to the uploaded image page to change the properties of this model?

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, httpresponse, django-urls

I have a list of images, there is a button to upload an image. It is necessary to validate the form in two fields and after successful loading they should get to the page of this image.

**models.py:**

```
class Picture(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField(blank=True, verbose_name='Ссылка на изображение')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='pictures/%Y/%m/%d', width_field='image_width', height_field='image_height',
                              blank=True, verbose_name='Изображение')
    image_width = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, verbose_name='Ширина изображения')
    image_height = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, verbose_name='Высота изображения')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name='Актуальность изображения')
    created = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, default=timezone.now, verbose_name='Дата создания записи')
    updated = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, default=timezone.now, verbose_name='Дата ред-ия записи')
```

**forms.py:**

```
class PictureCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Picture
        fields = ('url', 'image')

class PictureChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Picture
        fields = ('image_width', 'image_height')
```

**urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('add_picture/', views.add_picture, name='add_picture'),
    path('picture_detail/<int:id>/', views.picture_detail, name='picture_detail'),
    # re_path('picture_detail/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$', views.picture_detail, name='picture_detail')
]
```

**views.py:**

```
def add_picture(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PictureCreateForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home:picture_detail'))
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Ошибка, проверьте данные')
    else:
        form = PictureCreateForm()

    return render(request, 'add_picture.html', locals())

def picture_detail(request, id):
    picture = get_object_or_404(Picture, id=id)
    new_form = None

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PictureChangeForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_form = form.save(commit=False)
            new_form.picture = picture
            new_form.save()
            return redirect('home:picture_detail')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Ошибка, проверьте данные')
    else:
        form = PictureChangeForm()

    return render(request, 'picture_detail.html', locals())
```

Comment: and....what is the issue now? Whats *not* working now?

Comment: I think you need to add `*args` or `**kwargs` to your *redirect* and *reverse* like `return redirect('home:picture_detail', args=[new_form.id])` and `return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home:picture_detail', args=[form.id]))`

Comment: i corrected my code to **add_picture** and removed id
NoReverseMatch at /add_picture/
Reverse for **'picture_detail' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['picture_detail/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$']**